# Delete characters form a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm beginning in C++ and I have a simple task. As title said, I want to delete first and last character from a string for x times (where x is the lenght of the string). For example, if the string is **"example"**, the result will be:
    

`example 

xampl

amp

m

amp

xampl

example`

So far, I'm thinking like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

string sir = "Example";
int len, i;
len = sir.length();

for(i=1; i<=len; i++)
{
    sir.erase(sir.begin(), sir.end());
    cout<<sir;    
}
```

Or something like that... Can someone help me ?

Comment: how about using [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

Comment: You are asking about deleting elements, but in your example output your string starts mysteriously reconstituting itself. Have you left out part of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

- you can not use [`std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) with integral index such as `int i`,
  you need to use `std::string::iterator`
- but even if you use `std::string::iterator`, with the current logic you would be trying to increment an iterator after the `erase` has been called. (such iterator is invalid)
  Possible solution: assign `sir.begin()` to your iterator after each `erase`.

Here's how it could look like:

```
std::string sir = "Example";
for(string::iterator i = sir.begin(); i != sir.end(); i = sir.begin())
{
    sir.erase(i);
    std::cout << sir << std::endl;
}
```

outputs:

```
xample
ample
mple
ple
le
e
```

Just note that after erasing characters from your `std::string`, these characters are lost. You can not "restore" them. For the other half, you'll have to come with more sophisticated approach, but I'll leave that to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete both the first and last char.But in the example you also added them each step. It is not actually clear what you want. Whatever you want to delete or add the characters it is feasible to keep the string unchanged. So you should use ***substr***. Check it out [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).